# CFileDialog :: Browse folders

Tags: mfc, visual-c++

When I try to instantiate a `CFileDialog` object it shows both the folders and files. How do you create a `CFileDialog` that browses for folders alone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do it with `CFileDialog`.

Either you will use [SHBrowseForFolder Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762115(VS.85).aspx) or a wrapper for it, 
like [CFolderDialog - Selecting Folders.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2024/CFolderDialog-Selecting-Folders)

Comment: `SHBrowseForFolder` is heavily outdated. From the remarks: _"For Windows Vista or later, it is recommended that you use IFileDialog with the FOS_PICKFOLDERS option rather than the SHBrowseForFolder function. This uses the Open Files dialog in pick folders mode and is the preferred implementation."_

Comment: You actually can, if you are willing to reimplement `CFileDialog` - see  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66049570/10571377).

Comment: @Juv, the question is about displaying in the dialog only the folders.

Answer (score 20):

It is very simple, really.

Use [`CFolderPickerDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795962.aspx) which is derived from the class `CFileDialog`!

Comment: This class exists starting from Visual Studio 2010. we've just switched from VS2008 to VS2013, and IFileOpenDialog::SetOptions(FOS_PICKFOLDERS) surprisingly stopped working. 
IMHO it's against backward compatibility.

Answer (score 7):

Like someone mentioned, use [CFolderPickerDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795962.aspx) which works great. I would like to give you example how to use it especially when using the multi select flag:

```
CFolderPickerDialog folderPickerDialog(initialFolder, OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_ENABLESIZING, this,
        sizeof(OPENFILENAME));

    CString folderPath;

    if (folderPickerDialog.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {

        POSITION pos = folderPickerDialog.GetStartPosition();

        while (pos)
        {
            folderPath = folderPickerDialog.GetNextPathName(pos);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Starting from  Vista it's recommended to use IFileDialog with the FOS_PICKFOLDERS option ([see msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762115%28VS.85%29.aspx)):

```
CFileDialog od(TRUE/*bOpenFileDialog*/, NULL, NULL,
      OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT , NULL, NULL, 0,
      TRUE/*bVistaStyle*/);
   IFileOpenDialog * openDlgPtr = od.GetIFileOpenDialog();
   if ( openDlgPtr != NULL )
   {
      openDlgPtr->SetOptions(FOS_PICKFOLDERS);
      openDlgPtr->Release();
   }

   od.DoModal();
```

Comment: Starting Visual Studio 2010 this will not work. Use CFolderPickerDialog instead (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd795962%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

starting from windows vista,you can use the [Common Item Dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx) .

```
void CQiliRegrvDlg::OnBnClickedSelectDir()
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

// Create a new common open file dialog.
IFileOpenDialog *pfd = NULL;
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_PPV_ARGS(&pfd));
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // Set the dialog as a folder picker.
    DWORD dwOptions;
    hr = pfd->GetOptions(&dwOptions);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pfd->SetOptions(dwOptions | FOS_PICKFOLDERS);
    }

    // Set the title of the dialog.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pfd->SetTitle(L"Folder");
    }
    // Show the open file dialog.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pfd->Show(m_hWnd);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Get the selection from the user.
            IShellItem *psiResult = NULL;
            hr = pfd->GetResult(&psiResult);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                PWSTR pszPath = NULL;
                hr = psiResult->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszPath);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    m_appDir = pszPath;
                    SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATIC, m_appDir);
                    CoTaskMemFree(pszPath);
                }
                psiResult->Release();
            }
        }
    }

    pfd->Release();
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me the answer you are asking for is inside the code of

```
CMFCPropertyGridFileProperty::OnClickButton(CPoint /*point*/)
```

of the

```
<Your Visual Studio installation folder>\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\afxpropertygridctrl.cpp
```

file.

If you do not have access to the code, I will post the essential part of it:

```
CString strPath = m_varValue.bstrVal;
BOOL bUpdate = FALSE;

if (m_bIsFolder)
{
    if (afxShellManager == NULL)
    {
        CWinAppEx* pApp = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CWinAppEx, AfxGetApp());
        if (pApp != NULL)
        {
            pApp->InitShellManager();
        }
    }

    if (afxShellManager == NULL)
    {
        ASSERT(FALSE);
    }
    else
    {
        bUpdate = afxShellManager->BrowseForFolder(strPath, m_pWndList, strPath);
    }
}
else
{
    CFileDialog dlg(m_bOpenFileDialog, m_strDefExt, strPath, m_dwFileOpenFlags, m_strFilter, m_pWndList);
    if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        bUpdate = TRUE;
        strPath = dlg.GetPathName();
    }
}
```

As you see, Microsoft itself does not use the Cfiledialog class when wants to open a dialog for picking folders.

For using code like that, your application class MUST be derived from CWinAppEx, not CWinApp

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to do this - I found it in [codeguru: "Selected files and folders in CFileDialog"](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?114510-Selected-files-and-folders-in-CFileDialog)

If you are willing to make your own implementation of CFileDialog such as:
`class CMyFileDialog : public CFileDialog`

You can add the following code and it should work (It is slightly different from the [codeguru example](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?114510-Selected-files-and-folders-in-CFileDialog)):

```
// This code overrides the OnNotify message of the CFileDialog
// and catches the CDN_SELCHANGE, this way you can also do 
// something with the selected folders.
BOOL CMyFileDialog::OnNotify(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NMHDR* pNotificationParam = (NMHDR*)lParam;

    // Check that we got to the selection change notification.
    int code = pNotificationParam->code;
    if (code == CDN_SELCHANGE)
    {
        CStringArray theSelection;

        GetListControllSelectedItems(theSelection);

        // Do as you want with theSelection.
    }

    return CFileDialog::OnNotify(wParam, lParam, pResult);
}

// The following Code is accessing the selection in the CFileDialog
// and filling a string array with the selected names
BOOL CMyFileDialog::GetListControllSelectedItems(CStringArray& selectedItemNames)
{
    BOOL rc = FALSE;
    // Get the list control of the file dialog.
    CWnd* pParentWnd = GetParent();
    CWnd* pListControlWnd = pParentWnd->GetDlgItem(lst2);
    if (pListControlWnd) {

        // Get the selection from the list control.
        CListCtrl* pListCtrl = (CListCtrl*)(pListControlWnd->GetDlgItem(1));

        UINT selectionCount = pListCtrl->GetSelectedCount();

        // When there are items selected.
        if (selectionCount) {
            rc = TRUE;
            selectedItemNames.RemoveAll();
            POSITION itemPos = pListCtrl->GetFirstSelectedItemPosition();
            while (itemPos != NULL)
            {
                int itemNum = pListCtrl->GetNextSelectedItem(itemPos);
                CString currentItemName = pListCtrl->GetItemText(itemNum, 0);
                selectedItemNames.Add(currentItemName);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return rc;
}
```

Note: In [`CFileDialog::OnFileNameChange` of the Microsoft MFC documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class?view=msvc-160#onfilenamechange) they actually do hint toward this solution, but without elaborating too much.

I had a problem in my very old, legacy code, where I have a customized file dialog that actually needs to save a folder!!!

After twenty two years of hardship and pain, my code is now complete...